# Colorbox Opacity Attribute Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, colorbox

I am testing a colorbox (type of lightbox) on a site I'm working on. Everything works fine except for the 'opacity' attribute. There is no 'opacity' to the background of the site when the colorbox is open. The default is supposed to be "0.9" (the value is between 0 and 1) but even when I manually call the opacity value to be 0.9 it doesn't work. I checked the original colorbox.js that's loading to the page and the opacity is set to 0.9 so I can't figure out where the conflict is. I've tested it on Chrome, Safari and Firefox btw and they all do not work (I'm on a Mac so I can't test it on IE; I would be SHOCKED if it worked on IE if it's not working on these browsers). The site is here:

http://miller-media.com/sites/ncfit/index.html

If you click the banner in the upper right that says "We Will Pay You to Get in Shape!" it will open up the Colorbox.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that it can't find the background image for the overlay. The `background-image` source is pointing to `http://miller-media.com/sites/ncfit/css/images/overlay.png`, but it's not there.

If you want to get rid of the background image altogether, you could always set a `background-color` of `#000` to `#cboxOverlay`.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thanks. I was getting confused by all the CSS. This is my first time using Colorbox.